# html5 local storage, database connectivity

Tags: php, jquery, storage, local

I'm designing a website using html5,css and JavaScript mainly for client-side validation. Also I'm designing an app which will request the data entered in the website from a database. i.e if user searches for a contact, it should display the info entered in the form from the website. i don't know which route to take in terms of d/base connectivity. I'm new to html5 storage(local Storage) and php for server-side scripting. I understand that local storage is browser dependent and data is stored in the users browser.Also if you want to have registered users(premium members) is it better to have database in the server connected via php scripts or localStorage works pretty much the same?

Comment: suggest you forget about localStorage until you figure out what you want to use it for

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer everything but since you asked I can answer a few.

Q: User registration while also using a membership service PHP or localstorage?

A: PHP connected trough a Database never use localstorage for this.

---

Q: Search trough a site, LocalDB or Database?

A: Database.

Pretty much everything you mention there should use a database.